# Join two tables using linq, and fill a Dictionary of them

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I've been searching how to join two tables (Data and DataValues, one to many) and fill a dictionary of type .

The records of Data(s) might be thousands (e.g. 500,000 or more) and each Data may have 10 to 20 DataValues which makes it a much heavier query, so the performance is really important here.

here is the code I've write:

```
// Passed via the arguments, for example, sensorIDs would contain:
int[] sensorIDs = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 17, 18 };
Dictionary<Data, List<DataValue>> dict = new Dictionary<Data, List<DataValue>>();

foreach (Data Data in dt.Datas)
{
    var dValues = from d in dt.Datas
                        join dV in dt.DataValues on d.DataID equals dV.DataID
                        where (SensorIDs.Contains(dV.SensorID))
                        select dV;
    dict.Add(Data, dValues.ToList<DataValue>());
}
```

But this approach has a significant performance issue and takes a long time to execute.
Not sure if I need to use SQL Views. any suggestions?

Comment: How big is your datatable?

Comment: about 1200 records per day (just for Data) and each data may have 5 to 18 DataValue. the current rowcount of "Data" table is 125,361

Comment: Your query is incorrect as well by the way, you should be doing a select on `dt.DataValues` and include checking `Data.DataID == dV.DataID` as well in your `where` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're querying way too many times. You can do this in one query.

```
var dict = (from d in dt.Datas
            join dV in dt.DataValues on d.DataID equals dv.DataID
            where SensorIDs.Contains(dv.SensorID)
            select new { d, dV }).ToDictionary(o => o.d, o => o.dV.ToList());
```

In your `foreach` loop, you are fetching all `Data` and for each of them, you are doing the same thing.

**Edit:** Now that wasn't very clear, but I think you want to join only the `DataValue`s that are in the SensorIDs array. In this case:

```
var dict = (from d in dt.Datas
            let dV = (from dataValue in dt.DataValues
                      where SensorIDs.Contains(dataValue.SensorID) &&
                            dataValue.DataID = d.DataID
                      select dataValue)
            select new { d, dV }).ToDictionary(o => o.d, o => o.dV.ToList());
```

Comment: Without any clear idea on how `Data`, `DataValue` and `SeonsorID` relate to each other in his model and/or database, I can't say for sure. But the `Contains` with an array, in Entity Framework, translates to a `IN (.. the values in the array ..)` statement. So unless the array he's doing `Contains` with is very large, it has very small performance impact.

Comment: Well, thanks but the return type is a Dictionary of type <Data, DataValue> while I want to have <Data, List<DataValue>> (attention on List!)

Comment: @SimonBelanger yes that's right, but how can I join a datatable to a array of Ints?

Comment: What would be the purpose of joining an array? In any case you can't join things that are in your server and in your application at the same time. If you do, the whole table will come down to do an in-memory join

Comment: @SimonBelanger thanks a lot. worked well and the performance is just FINE :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a `foreach` loop in this case, you can use group join to create the dictionary straight from linq which should give you better performance.

```
dict=(from DataValue d in dt.DataValues
           where sensorIDs.Contains(d.SensorID)
       group d by d.DataID 
           into datavalues
       join data in dt.Datas 
           on datavalues.Key equals data.DataId
       select new { 
         Key = data, 
         Value = datavalues
       }).ToDictionary(a=>a.Key,a=>a.Value.ToList());
```

or you can use linq expression methods

```
dict = dt.DataValues.Where(d=>sensorIDs.Contains(d.SensorID))
            .GroupBy(a=>a.DataID)
             .Join(dt.Datas,a=>a.Key,a=>a.DataId,
                    (a,b)=>new{Key=b,Value=a.ToList()})
        .ToDictionary(a=>a.Key,a=>a.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need foreach loop. Try something like this in general:

```
var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => columns.Select(column => 
                     new { Column = column.ColumnName, Value = dataRow[column] })
                 .ToDictionary(data => data.Column, data => data.Value));
```

Also, consider reading this: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/