# Entity Framework Core store joined table in a variable

Tags: c#, forms, entity-framework

I'm joining two tables with Entity Framework like so :

```
List<Drivers> drivers;
drivers = (from dr in context.Drivers
          join per in context.Person on dr.dr_no_person equals per.per_id
          select new { dr, per }).ToList();
```

Of course it doesn't work since `{dr, per}` is an anonymous type and cannot be translated to `Drivers`.

My question: is there any way to store what my query returns in a variable, so that I could return it as a list to eventually show it in a `DataTable`?

Comment: use `var` as a result type and see what the compiler selects as a `type` ?

Comment: @FelixD The result would be `List<anontype1`[Drivers,Person]>`.

Comment: so you could still access `Drivers` and `Person` - isn't that what he wants ?

Comment: I'm not sure what he wants any more.

Comment: @NetMage Indeed. Counting the fact that they can (should) add `Person` navigation property to `Driver` class and avoid the whole query, the question sounds like a good candidate for closing.

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330949/4610605) is what you want to do.

Comment: why not simply select dr instead of the anonymous type, if you only need drivers anyways? you've did the join already and retrieve more data than necessary, only to filter the additional data out afterwards again?

Comment: It is possible that my query is wrong, I am quite new at this <.<, but selecting only dr returns only dr's informations

Comment: so you need the person information as well? then create a new anonymous type, even with select new {car=dr.Car, name=per.Name...} if you don't need the complete objects anymore. Otherwise @NetMage's answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah that did it, Thanks a lot mate :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either declare `drivers` to be a list of anonymous type:

```
var drivers = (...).ToList();
```

Or you can create a `Drivers` object in the query:

```
drivers = (from dr in context.Drivers
           join per in context.Person on dr.dr_no_person equals per.per_id
           select new Drivers { ... }).ToList();
```

If you want to assign the result to a simple `DataGridView` and have columns displayed, you will have to pull out the values you want.

```
var drivers = (from dr in context.Drivers
               join per in context.Person on dr.dr_no_person equals per.per_id
               select new { dr.dr_no_person, per.per_id, per.name, ... }).ToList();
```

Unfortunately LINQ doesn't have an easy equivalent to `*` from SQL. I have a (quite complicated) extension method that allows combining two anonymous types, but it isn't for the faint-hearted, and it isn't strongly typed - it returns the new anonymous type as `object`.

Comment: then that `join` would be completely useless ...

Comment: No, the `join` would restrict the `drivers` to those that have a matching `Person`. Why did you declare `drivers` a `List<Drivers>` if that isn't what you wanted?

Comment: right - got confused ...

Comment: I'm able to store it in a variable thanks to you, it doesn't show properly in my DataGridView thought, it gives me only 2 columns filled with objects named [myprojectnamespace].Drivers/Person.
Thanks for answering the not so clear question, Sorry about that ^^' . Too bad it caused an other problem.

Comment: the objects are not "named" like that, it is their runtime type. 2 columns is incorrect if you do the binding correctly - obviously you can't bind the objects to the view directly.